# C# equivalent to iOS SDK NSDate and NSTimeInterval

Tags: c#, ios, windows-phone-7

Can anyone please tell me what is the C# equivalent to iOS SDK NSDate and NSTimeInterval ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read

- [DateTime Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)
- [TimeSpan Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Here is example:

- [DateTime Subtraction Operator (DateTime, TimeSpan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326710%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

DateTime and TimeSpan.  Both a part of system.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at class/method mapping tools Microsoft has published?

- [iPhone/iOS to WP7 mapping tool](http://wp7mapping.interoperabilitybridges.com/Home/Library?source=iPhone)
- [Android to WP7 mapping tool](http://wp7mapping.interoperabilitybridges.com/Home/Library?source=Android)